# How memory overhead factor works

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

To start things off I have the following scenario:
I am deploying a structured streaming application in spark 3.5 using RocksDB. The issue is that RocksDB is consuming a lot of memory. Let's say that I have 10GB RAM for one executor but looking on the machine using 'top' I can see that the process is growing from 10GB to more than 18-19GB and at some point the machine is just running out of memory.

Reading the documentation I found out a parameter 'spark.executor.memoryOverheadFactor' but I don't really understand how it works. What I would like to happen is if an executor from my job fail I would like to go on a machine that is having x GB unused + spark.executor.memory * spark.executor.memoryOverheadFactor. I would like to avoid submitting on the same machine where the job was unable to find enough RAM.

This is a bit strange because we have to reserve so much memory for those processes and the spark cluster is using 16GB RAM from 32. I am open to other suggestions.

I already tried spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.rocksdb.boundedMemoryUsage, spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.rocksdb.maxMemoryUsageMB even spark.executor.memoryOverheadFactor but I was unable to understand how it works.